# Ejecutar un query a una base de datos muy grande

Tags: mysql

Tengo un sistema web que consulta una base de datos MYSQL, mis tablas han crecido a tal grado que cuando se ejecuta algunos querys los resultados tardan mucho en procesarse y a veces ni siquiera llegan a un resultado, ya he tratado de optimizar la consulta y he buscado posibles alternativas como creas vistas o agregar indices etc, mi pregunta es si es profesional y válido en la administración de una base de datos crear tablas de "archivo muerto" para poner ahí los registros de una tabla que ya no se usan pero se requieren conservar a razón de que las tablas que si se consulten disminuyan su tamaño y de esta manera lograr que el resultado de los querys se obtengan más rápido.

Muchas gracias a todos.

Comment: Pues creo que lo recomendable es que crees una base espejo donde guardes el archivo muerto, es recomendable que cada cierto se de mantenimiento y no dejes registros que ya no se utilizan.

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. También puedes revisar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para lo mismo.Saludos.